# How to get an adjacency matrix with weights?

Tags: matlab, graph, adjacency-matrix

How to get an adjacency matrix with weights?

Suppose I have

```
s=[1 1 2 2 2 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 6 7];

t=[2 3 4 5 3 5 6 5 7 8 6 8 7 8];

w=[3 5 4 7 4 9 8 3 11 8 3 9 8 7];

G=digraph(s,t,w)
```

It should have been created with this

```
A = adjacency(G,'weighted')
```

but marks an error that says

> Error using digraph/adjacency Too many input arguments.

When I type `A = adjacency(G)` set all costs as `1`.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`adjacency` only accepts 1 input argument, which is why you are receiving that error. The function is only designed to return values of 0 or 1.

You can get the weighted adjacency matrix from the following, taken from the MATLAB documentation for the `adjacency` function.

```
nn = numnodes(G);
[s,t] = findedge(G);
A = sparse(s,t,G.Edges.Weight,nn,nn)
```

Alternatively, you can construct the weighted adjacency matrix without using graph objects.

```
nn = max([s, t]);
A = zeros(nn);
for i = 1:length(s)
  A(s(i), t(i)) = w(i);
end
```

Comment: The `'weighted'` argument for `adjacency` works in MATLAB R2018a and later versions. A slightly more compact form for constructing `A` without graph objects is: `A(sub2ind(size(A), s, t)) = w;` (instead of the loop).

Comment: Good observation, I wasn't aware of that.